# Trying to sort through array object using .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

I've got the following code where I'm trying to loop through the array of objects, but for some reason it's telling me data.map is not a function, even though I know data has content in it.

```
function Tree({ data }) {
  let count = 0;
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(item => {
        count += 1;
        console.log("Item", item.name);
        return (
          <div key={count} className="node">
            {/* {item.name} */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
export default Tree;
```

When I change it over to Object.entries, I get stuff back, but that's not how I've done this in the past so I'm a little confused on the issue here.

```
function Tree({ data }) {
  let count = 0;
  return (
    <>
      {Object.entries(data).map(item => {
        count += 1;
        console.log("Item", item.name);
        return (
          <div key={count} className="node">
            {/* {item.name} */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
export default Tree;
```

The array object is constructed like so:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    name: Brannon,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: John,
  }
]
```

Comment: console.log/debug the data before you map and prepare yourself to be surprised that `data` is actually not an array, but an object.

Comment: Even though it's contained within [ ]?

Comment: Are you *sure* that `data` is (always) an array? Also, an `item` produced from `Object.entries` never will have a `.name`.

Comment: Yes, because I created it in the same format as I described above.

Comment: I have now updated the above code to better reflect what I have.

Comment: Ok, I see what the issue, apparently, was.  I was setting initial state as {} and then converting it based on the array returned, which was causing the code to break.  I have now updated the initial state to carry [], which has solved the issue.  Very annoying,.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote though...

Answer (score 1):

`Console log data`. You will get this message when the data you are trying to map is not an array. When you run Object entries you are turning the object into an array consisting of its keys and values. So this implies that the original data is just a plain object and not an array.

Also just a tip `map` will auto handle index for you if you pass it as a second parameter instead of manually handling it as you are.

```
{Object.entries(data).map( (item, count) => {
    //count += 1; remove this it will auto increment
    console.log("Item", item.name);
    return (
      <div key={count} className="node">
        {/* {item.name} */}
      </div>
    );
})}
```

Comment: @zfrisch won't work for what? In this case OP is only using it as a map key so it absolutely will work

Answer (score 0):

Try,and write console.log output of data if it not help

```
function Tree({ data }) {
    console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));
      return (
        <>
          { data && data.map((item, index) => {
            console.log("Item", item.name);
            return (
              <div key={index} className="node">
                {/* {item.name} */}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </>
      );
    }
    export default Tree;
```